# Axis2 create persistent connection

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis, keep-alive

I want to consume a webservice made in .NET. For generating my source code, I used Axis2 based on the WSDL of the web service. I launched Axis without options.

I can call the first method of the webservice. This is the authentification method "Connect" of the web service. After this, I call again a new method, but the webservice indicate that I'm not any more connected. The support of the web service told me it's because after I call the connect method, the connection is closed by java. And this, the webservice assume that I'm disconnected and close my session.

To solve this problem, my successif call of the both method should maintain the connection in live. However, I'm not sure that Axis2 suggest this functionalities, is it true?

How can I maintain connection between different calls?

Here is my java code :

```
WinbooksWebServiceStub stub = new WinbooksWebServiceStub("http://myUrl/Service.asmx");
Connect c = new Connect();
c.setKey("KEY");
c.setUser("USER");
c.setPass("PSW");

ConnectResponse resp = stub.connect(c);
ConnectParser connecterParser = new ConnectParser();//works and return the Token

HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld();
HelloWorldResponse Hresp = stub.helloWorld(h); //the result tell me that I'm not connected
```

If I follow the answer, I apply method on my stub object, I got this error Exception in thread "main"

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Attempted read on closed stream.
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430) 
at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:64)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:179)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:108)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at com.logidrive.ws.WinbooksWebServiceStub.connect(WinbooksWebServiceStub.java:4251)
at Main.main(Main.java:44) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.isReadAllowed(AutoCloseInputStream.java:183)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:107)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
at org.apache.axiom.om.util.DetachableInputStream.read(DetachableInputStream.java:147)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:169)
at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getCharSetEncoding(BuilderUtil.java:294)
at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:51)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two questions going on.  I'm not sure why your not connected, but you can do an http connection pool for high volume requests.

Here is a blog that talks about how to do that [Axis2 Blog](http://amilachinthaka.blogspot.com/2009/05/improving-axis2-client-http-transport.html)

Also, Here is some code for the setup from [Here](http://ratheeshpkumar.blogspot.com/2010/09/axis2-15-connectionpooltimeoutexception.html)

**EDIT** Update the code

```
import org.apache.axis2.client.Stub;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext;
import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams;

public static void setContextProperties(Stub stub) {

    // Set the max connections to 20 and the timeout to 20 seconds
    MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();

    HttpConnectionManagerParams params = new HttpConnectionManagerParams();
    params.setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(20);
    params.setMaxTotalConnections(20);
    params.setSoTimeout(20000);
    params.setConnectionTimeout(20000);
    multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.setParams(params);

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager);

    stub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext().getConfigurationContext().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpClient);
}
```

Comment: Thx, I tried your solution, but I got the error. I wrote the message error in the other answer..Sorry

Comment: I didn't let this go, as it was bothering me.  To reuse the connection, call this before calling connect, as it is used on the socket open.  I had an issue with the pool setup, I'll work on it... stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, new Boolean(true));

Comment: Edited the code.  It should work now.  Just remember to set the context properties before calling any routines.  Also, that above one liner in the comments will give you two connections by default.